Sci-Fi Movie Identification - New Home for Earth
I'm looking for assistance in identifying a movie that I saw sometime in the late to mid 1990's, but movie could have been made in the 1980's.  It was on VHS and I'm not sure it ever had a theatrical release, definitely a B-Movie type.  Some details that I recall.  Saw in United States, english language film, color.  

A crew of ~5-7 people on a long range exploration trip looking for a new home for Earth.  Definitely to another star system.
Crew wore jumpsuits for their uniforms.  Looked mostly normal, much like what NASA is using for astronauts.  
They awaken from cold sleep to find that the captain has killed himself (hanging) after discovering that the earth has destroyed itself while they were asleep.
There is some Virtual Reality room (googles, helmet style) that they go to, but it seems more like a psychological profiling room rather than something they can control.  Crew uses it for recreation, but I think the android is using it to stress test/evaluate the crew and the sims turn into nightmares.
One of the crew (medical/psych/political officer?) ends up being an android.  Rest of crew is surprised by this.  I think he turns out to have killed the captain.
Remaining crew die/kill each other until all that is left is one man and one woman.  
They both then awaken to find that they were still on earth all along, as the mission was supposed to test their ability to handle a long isolation and cold sleep rather than actually explore (or maybe repopulate the earth)?  
Earth is a wasteland, I remember them coming out of the pods, seeing the other crew members dead in their pods, a guard at his post but skeletonized (so long dead).  

The ship isn't very large and there doesn't appear to be much advanced technology other than the android, cold sleep and the VR.  So more of a near future / hard science type of movie.

Can it be Doomsday Machine (1972)? It has some similarities.

@GustavoGabriel, sorry it's not that, although I've added your suggestion to my list of movies to watch.  The ship was definitely going to another star system.

I found it!  It was Terminal Voyage (1994) / Star Quest  (http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114533/?ref_=nv_sr_1).  I found it using https://www.whatismymovie.com/.

Oh! Nice find. =)

@JonathanFite You should post the answer so the question doesn't remain open.  (The film sounds very interesting btw, even knowing the spoiler;)

I know you already find your movie, but I think I will post a more detailed answer. The movie is Terminal Voyage (AKA: Star Quest or Starquest).
The movie details match perfectly with the details you provided in your question. 

In 2035, global warming rendered the Earth barely inhabitable and its human population is on the verge of extinction. The Earth Federation sends a space ship on a century-long trip to a distant planet Trion which could be suitable for colonization. The eight crew-members come from Russia, United States, China, United Kingdom, France, and Saudi Arabia.
As the ship approaches Trion, the crew wakes from hibernation. They immediately find a decomposed corpse of the Captain in his capsule. The ship's XO, Commander Hollis, assumes command. When he reads a secure transmission from Earth received while they were sleeping, he commits suicide, leaving a note that he "joins his loved ones". The new CO, Lieutenant Jammad, reveals the content of the message: the Earth has been devastated in a nuclear holocaust.
Zinovitz discovers that the ship's systems have been tampered with. A fight for power ensues and Becker, as a representative of the government, relieves Jammad from command. He is soon found dead in a malfunctioned virtual reality simulator. The remaining crew-members suspect that Becker killed the officers and use force to arrest her, discovering in process that she is an android.
When questioned, Becker denies any guilt then sets off the self-destruction sequence. Granier and Han are too devastated to continue and commit suicide with a morphine overdose, and Reese and Zinovitz make it to the escape capsule. As the countdown reaches zero, they find themselves in an underground simulation facility stationed on Earth. There was no space flight - it is their final test, an "extreme stress simulation" scenario which involved the death of the commanding officer and multiple system failures. The crew have only been in hibernation for 6 months, and Hollis, Jammad and Becker apparently knew about the test.
However the nuclear war on Earth was indeed real, and the facility is empty and abandoned. The film ends with a view of a destroyed city, as Reese and Zinovitz look on to uncertain future.

